# A polynomial $z^n-1$ has $n$ distinct zeros.

Tags: polynomials, induction

I want to get help to prove this one (just by induction method if possible.)

I'm trying to factorize $z^{k+1}-1$ with $z^k-1$ to see if it is possible, but this is where I'm stuck. (I supposed that $z^k-1$ has $k$ distinct zeros.)

Is it even possible to prove this only with a simple mathematical induction method?

And, it is over $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Hint:  if a polynomial $p(z)$ has a multiple root $\alpha$ then $p'(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the hint!! By the way, I just wonder if this hint is related to the mathematical induction method.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true - for example, in a finite field with $n$ elements, $z^{n + 1} - 1$ cannot possibly have $n + 1$ zeroes. Are you talking about complex zeroes?

Comment: This is not a question for which induction will help.

Comment: Note:  my hint only addresses the distinctness of the roots, and even then care must be taken in characteristic $p$.  Please edit your post to indicate what underlying field you had in mind.

Comment: @MarkSaving I edited my post. Yes, it is over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for pointing it out. I just edited the post. It is over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @lulu Do you mean repeated root? Are these both the same thing?

Comment: @lonestudent  Yes, those are the same thing.  I just mean a root $\alpha$ such that $(x-\alpha)^2\,|\,p(x)$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. If a polynomial has $n$ repeating roots, its $n-1$ derivatives must be zero at the root point.  Is this true too?

Comment: @lonestudent  Well...that's true if you have a root with multiplicity $n$.   Somewhat different from what you wrote.

Comment: @lonestudent If it is over $\mathbb{C}$, then you will see $p'(z)$ has a factor $(z-\alpha )$

Comment: @lulu I'm still figuring out how your hint could prove this one. And, I think I still need some more hints. Do I need to use the contrapositive statement? And, repeat the process for all zeros?

Comment: Well, if $p(z)=z^k-1$, what is $p'(z)$?   What are the zeroes of $p'(z)$?   Are any of those also zeroes of $p(z)$?

Comment: @lulu $p'(z)=nz^{n-1}$ =, thus only zeros of $p'(z)$ is $0$. But, $0$ can't be a zero of $p(z)$. Am I approaching to the right answer?

Comment: Well, that's all you need!  Since $0$ is the only root of $p'(z)$, $0$ is the only possible candidate for a multiple root of $p(z)$.  But, as you say, $p(0)\neq 0$ so we are done.

Comment: @lulu You're awesome! Thank you, it really helped me a lot!

Comment: @lulu $p'(x)=kx^{k-1}$ and if $p'(x)=0$ then $x=0$. (I got your point for the current question) Actually I wanted to generalize, for all polynomials.I thought that $N-1$ derivatives of the polynomial (at the same root point) are zero if there are $N$ repeating roots.

Comment: @lonestudent  You keep referring to "$N$ repeated roots".  That sounds like you mean something divisible by $(x-r_1)^2\cdots (x-r_N)^2$.  But higher derivatives of that need not vanish at the $r_i$.

Comment: @lonestudent  On the other hand, a root of multiplicity $N$  means that $(x-\alpha)^N$ divides our polynomial.  That is very different, and in that case we do indeed get that the first $N-1$ derivatives all vanish at $\alpna$.

Comment: @lulu yes, but sorry my English is problematic. I mean, if $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^N(x-\beta )^M...$ then $f^{(N-1)}(\alpha)=0, f^{(M-1)}(\beta)=0  ..$ I wanted to ask if this is true..

Comment: @lonestudent   Yes, that is true.

Comment: @lulu I got it. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First answer**

The question as stated is wrong in general. In the field $\mathbb F_p$ where $p $ is a prime, $q_n(x)=x^n -1$ has $1$ for only root when $n=p$.

Also in $\mathbb R$, $q_n$ has at most two roots.

**Second answer**

Your statement is nearly true in an algebraically closed field. I say nearly true as the roots may not be distinct. To prove it, $q_n$ has at least one root, let’s call it $a$. Make the long division of $q_n(x)$ by $x-a$ to get the result by induction.